# Nsdata.length return wrong image size

Tags: ios, iphone, file, uiimage, nsdata

```
 NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 UIImage *imageCaptured=[imagePickerInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 NSData *imgchekc=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageCaptured,1);        
 NSUInteger fileLength = [imgchekc length];
 NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d %d ",[imgchekc length],fileLength);
```

- hi, i am using this code to get image size in bytes for restrict user
  to upload >5MB size image.
- But this code gives me 10698536 byte for 4.4MB image which is
  wrong.Please tell me how to get actual file size.

Comment: How did you find the 4.4MB, by saving to disk?

Comment: @Wain i am trying to upload image from my simulator to server ,so i know the image size.If size is >5MB i want to show alert vie,but i am not getting actual file size in bytes

Comment: Which file though? You aren't using the file data on disk because you use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to create something different...

Comment: This code cannot produce "10698536 byte for 4.4MB" output. Provide the real data

Answer (score 2):

You need to be checking the same thing. You have a file on disk that you load into an image. You then convert that image into JPEG data (with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`). This data now has no relationship (in terms of size) to the data on disk.

If you just want to upload the file on disk, don't load it into an image and then convert the data, just upload it. To get the size of the file you can use `NSFileManager`, `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` and `NSFileSize`.

If you want to convert to JPEG then your code is ok, you just probably don't want to use `1` for the `compressionQuality` as this will result in a larger amount of data. Try `0.75` and see what the difference is.